# How do I prevent very similar if/else Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, slim-lang

I have a Rails 5 app where I have many if/else statements that almost outputs the same content. Here is an example:

```
- if @url.include?('coaches')
  .page-container
    .container.margin-bottom-xs.spacer-minus
      .row.spacer-md
        .col-md-12
          .margin-bottom-sm
            .row
              - @am_coaches.each do |user|
                .col-md-4
                  .small-card.shadow.margin-bottom-sm
                    = image_tag(user.avatar.url, class: 'medium-img')
                    = link_to [user.team, user] do
                      .small-overlay
                        .row
                          .col-md-11
                            .post-category
                              - if user.city?
                                = user.city
                                |,&nbsp;
                              - if user.country?
                                = user.country
                            .post-title.text-default
                              = user.name
                            .post-time-ago.text-muted
                              - unless user.age_group.blank?
                                = user.age_group
                                |,&nbsp;
                              = user.team.name

                          .col-md-1.text-right
                            - if user.facebook_url
                              .post-category
                                = link_to "http://www.facebook.com/#{user.facebook_url}",
                                target: '_blank'
                                  i.icon-facebook
                            - if user.twitter_url
                              .post-category
                                = link_to "http://www.twitter.com/#{user.twitter_url}",
                                target: '_blank'
                                  i.icon-twitter
                            - if user.instagram_handle
                              .post-category
                                = link_to "http://www.instagram.com/#{user.instagram_handle}",
                                target: '_blank'
                                  i.icon-instagram

- elsif @url.include?('users')
  .spacer-lg
    - @skills.uniq.sort.reverse.each do |skill|
      .container.spacer-sm
        span.section-heading.text-semibold
          = skill.humanize

        .margin-bottom-sm
          .row.spacer-md
            - @am_users[skill].each do |user|
              .col-md-4
                .small-card.shadow.margin-bottom-sm
                  = image_tag(user.avatar.url, class: 'medium-img')
                  = link_to [user.team, user] do
                    .small-overlay
                      .row
                        .col-md-11
                          .post-category
                            - if user.city?
                              = user.city
                              |,&nbsp;
                            - if user.country?
                              = user.country
                          .post-title.text-default
                            = user.name
                          .post-time-ago.text-muted
                            - unless user.age_group.blank?
                              = user.age_group
                              |,&nbsp;
                            = user.team.name

                        .col-md-1.text-right
                          - if user.facebook_url
                            .post-category
                              = link_to "http://www.facebook.com/#{user.facebook_url}",
                              target: '_blank'
                                i.icon-facebook
                          - if user.twitter_url
                            .post-category
                              = link_to "http://www.twitter.com/#{user.twitter_url}",
                              target: '_blank'
                                i.icon-twitter
                          - if user.instagram_handle
                            .post-category
                              = link_to "http://www.instagram.com/#{user.instagram_handle}",
                              target: '_blank'
                                i.icon-instagram
```

As you can see, 80% of this is duplicated code. I'm trying to improve the way I write my apps and would love to know how I can make this nicer.

My initial thought was to take the loops and put them into a shared view. However, if doing so the variables are not recognised.

Any suggestions on how I should approach this now and in the future?

Comment: There are multiple refactorings here, both to helpers and partials. But you probably want the code review stack exchange.

Comment: Why Stack Exchange and not Stack Overflow?

Comment: The code review site is for working code that wants to be improved. SO is for code that doesn't work. (That's a rough approximation but in this case, close enough.)